# Animate dropdown menu using "max-height"

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I've made a responsive drop down hamburger menu and I like how it works so far, except for one thing. I'd like to make it slowly dropdown, as of right now it just appears when the hamburger menu icon is clicked. I read about using `max-height: 0` and then giving it a `max-height` after bing clicked, but I tried that method and wasn't successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('nav ul').classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

.toggle-menu,
.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.expand {
  max-height: 500px;
  display: block;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  nav .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  .toggle-menu,
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .hamburger {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 3%;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    float: none;
    /*--- body content goes underneath ul when expanded ---*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 99;
    /*------------------------------------------*/
    display: none;
  }
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    background-color: coral;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle-menu">
      <span class="hamburger">|||</span>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use `display: none` to `display: block`, and transition does work but it waits for the transition to end and then adds `display: block;` so you dont see the transition.

You can just remove the `display: none` and add `overflow: hidden;` on your `ul` element.

Comment: Woah thanks a lot! appreciate the help. Don't mean to bother ya much, but do you have any advice on how to make it transition back up? if not, it's cool haha I'm glad you helped me get the down transition!

Comment: @eric Add the `transition` element to the `ul`  and not to the `.expand` class, cause when you click it away, the expand class is gone so there is no `transition` property anymore. NP

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform:scale()` to animate it like below with `opacity` to make it more intuitive..

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('nav ul').classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

.toggle-menu,
.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.expand {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  nav .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  .toggle-menu,
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .hamburger {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 3%;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 99;
    transform: scale(1, 0);
    transition: all .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    background-color: coral;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle-menu">
      <span class="hamburger">|||</span>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

However if you want the `max-height` solution remove `display:none`...you can't animate it with `display:none;`...And on `max-height:0` set `overflow:hidden` to hide the overflow content.

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('nav ul').classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

.toggle-menu,
.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

ul {
  float: right;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.expand {
  max-height: 500px;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  nav .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  .toggle-menu,
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .hamburger {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 3%;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    float: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    z-index: 99;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .5s linear;
  }
  ul li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    background-color: coral;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle-menu">
      <span class="hamburger">|||</span>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s; /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */
```

Try this, I see that you already have the transition attribuut, but you still need some extra parameters and a transition-deley that removes the transition delay so the will be visible while the other styles transition.

Answer (score 0):

Css property does not work with `display: none` therefore you should either play with height: 0 or top in some negative value to hide it from the canvas, once you append the class expand reset the height or top position again.

```js
document.querySelector('.hamburger').addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector('nav ul').classList.toggle('expand');
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.container{
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

nav{
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo{
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

.toggle-menu,
.hamburger{
  display: none;  
}

.hamburger{
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

ul{
  float: right;
}

ul li{
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a{
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.expand{
  top: 60px;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}




@media(max-width: 768px){
  
  nav .container{
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  nav{
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .logo{
    margin-left: 2%;
  }
  
  .toggle-menu,
  .hamburger{
    display: block;
  }
  
  .hamburger{
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 3%;
  }
  
  ul{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    float: none;
    /*--- body content goes underneath ul when expanded ---*/
    position: absolute;
    top: -600px;
    z-index: 99;
    /*------------------------------------------*/
  
  }
  
  ul li{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  ul li a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    background-color: coral;
  }
  
  ul li a:hover{
    background-color: orange;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
  <div class="container">
    
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="toggle-menu">
      <span class="hamburger">|||</span>
    </div>
    
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 1 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 2 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Lorem 3 ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati sed facilis doloribus quasi consequatur illo asperiores non labore rem suscipit enim vel, aliquam tempore amet quod totam harum, incidunt quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi quisquam quam eius harum iusto dolore suscipit? Neque, tempora eius cumque porro nulla fugit eum aliquam exercitationem voluptas nostrum corrupti autem?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```